# How can we know that when n1 and n2 is 1, the output is 0? What makes the circuit a NAND?

Tags: circuit-analysis, nand

We start with the obvious part of the circuit, N1 and N2 are in series.

I was given the truth table, where both N1 and N2 are 1, then the output is 0 and the rest is 1.

By this picture, how can we know that when n1 and n2 are 1, the output is 0? What makes the transistor circuit a NAND?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work through this with understanding of transistors.

Consider the following:
[image: diagram]
When the upper input is high (orange) then P1 is turned off and N1 is turned on (P fets become closed-circuit when the voltage from gate to source is negative, and N fets become closed-circuit when the voltage from gate to source is positive). When the lower input is low (blue) then P2 is turned on and N2 is turned off.

As the path of the output to ground is disconnected by N2, and the path to Vdd is connected by P2, the output arising from the particular input of A=1 B=0 appear to be 1.

Going through this simple process allow you to construct a truth table. Whether this module is indeed a NAND circuit is left as an exercise for you.

Comment: so when N1 and N2 is on (1), P1 is turned off ( 0 ) and P2 is turn on (1), which leads to P1 is turned off when A and B output 1 , and P2 is turn on when A and C output 0?     with that information, we can complete a truth table of A, B,C, F ?

Comment: P1 is hard wired to be the opposite of N1, and same for P2 to N2. When you reason and intuit about circuits, make sure to pay close attention to cause/effect (if there are any). N1 and N2 are both controlled by input signals that are wired directly to P1 and P2, but N1 cannot directly "control" or "lead to" P1 besides sharing the same input signals. (Label those two inputs!)

Comment: And to address your question, if N1 and N2 are both on, neither P should be on or else there will be a short circuit. Give it another try. (Also you can use the reasoning that in order for N1 or N2 to be on, the voltage on their gate should be logically high. This lets you know what the gate voltage of P1 and P2 is)

Comment: when N1 and N2 are 1, both p are 0 which mean A and B (I) outputs 1 and A and C (J) outputs 1.    Ok. Thank you.